# Plotar função em PYTHON ou MATLAB

Tags: python, matemática, matlab

Galera preciso plotar uma função e não consigo achar ferramentas legais para isso, pois a função tem por definição constantes, e achei por bem usar uma linguagem de programação pra isso, porém não sei python , nem matlab, as únicas que pensei pra esse caso; se alguém puder me ajudar ai e mandar o código e a imagem gráfica, ou qualquer um dos dois ajudaria bastante, pois é pra um relatório de faculdade.

Segue a função:

```
f(X0) = 76
f(X1) = 121
f(Xn+2) = (2 * f(Xn+1) - f(Xn)) + 18
```

Comment: matlab custa alguns milhares de reais pela licença de uso, enquanto Python é grátis, aberto e livre - queria entender melhor como  "tanto faz"

Answer (score 2):

"Funções" são um dos conceitos fundamentais de linguagens de programação modernas - e derivam justamente do conceito de funções em matemática.

Python é uma linguagem de programação robusta, que pode atender o que você precisa - Matlab é uma ferramenta de domínio específico da matemática, desenvolvida e publicada por um único vendedor (empresa), e é algo meio hibrido entre matemática e linguagens de programação - com os avanços das bibliotecas abertas de matemática nos últimos anos, talvez tenha se tornado obsoleto. Então continuo a resposta usando Python.

O primeiro passo é traduzir sua função da notação matemática para uma função em Python - ela fica assim:

```
def f(x):
   if x == 0:
       return 76
   elif x == 1:
       return 121
   return  (2 * f(x - 1) - f(x - 2)) + 18
```

Esse tipo de função, que faz uma chamada a ela mesma, é chamada de "função recursiva". Uma chamada a mesma vai retornar um único número para quem a chamou de "fora", apesar de internamente ela ser percorrida várias vezes.

Aqui alguns exemplos da função sendo chamada -

```
In [30]: f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)                                                                                 
Out[30]: (76, 121, 184, 265, 364)
```

Na verdade, no "maravilhoso mundo da programação", sua função não precisa ser fixa - se você desejar experimentar com outros parâmetros, ela pode ser escrita assim - 
e você pode passar qualquer um deles opcionalmente se ela for escrita dessa forma.

```
def f(x, x0=76, x1=121, x2=18):
   if x == 0:
       return x0
   elif x == 1:
       return x1
   return  (2 * f(x - 1 1, x0, x1, x2) - f(x - 2, x0, x1, x2)) + x2
```

Para poder usar a função você vai precisar ter um ambiente para usar isso - como você é iniciante, e quer explorar matemática, eu recomendo o uso do ipython notebook - aqui tem um artigo detalhado: https://medium.com/horadecodar/como-instalar-o-jupyter-notebook-windows-e-linux-20701fc583c

Depois de a função estar no lugar, você pode passar ao ato de plotar a função - para isso em Python usamos a biblioteca "matplotlib" - 
se você instalou o jupyter notebook com o anaconda, como no artigo que passei,, a matplotlib já está instalada. Senão, com  seu ambiente Python ativo digite "pip install matplotlib" no shell do sistema operacional.

Agora, finalmente, antes de plotar, há um outro aspecto da sua função - para cada valor com o qual ela é chamada, exceto 0 e 1, são geradas outras 2 chamadas de função, com valores menores. Algumas centenas de chamadas de função não são problema algum para o Python ou computadores modernos, no entanto, essa função gera expnencialmente mais chamadas - uma chamada com o valor "34" geraria mais que 2 ** 32 = 4 bilhões de chamadas de função - cada uma tendo que criar internamente um objeto de "frame" e ser processada- talvez o tempo restante de vida do Universo não fosse o suficiente para isso, mesmo com uma CPU i9 rodando a 5GHz.

No entanto isso aconece computacionalmente por que para cada chamada, o computador *vai* calcular novamente os falores de f(x-1) e f(x - 2) a partir do "zero". Quando fazemos as contas em papel, e estamos preenchendo uma tabela com os valores de "f(x)", os valores para f(x - 1) e f(x - 2) estão prontamente disponíveis nas linahs de cima da tabela.

Então, para poder computar valores dessa função, temos que criar o equivalente computacional dessa tabela com os valores anteriores. Em Python, isso é feito com o decorador de funções "lru_cache". Internamente ele faz exatamente o que fazemos em papel: anota os valores com os quais f(x) já foi chamada, e, se x for repetido, usa o valor já retornado da primeira vez.

Isso efetivamente acaba com o aspecto exponencial da sua função `f` - já que, ao cálculaur "f(4) ", por exemplo, ele internametne os valores de f(3) e f(2) - mas quando for cálcular f(2), o valor já está na tabela - uma vez que foi preciso durante o cálcul de f(3).

A declaração da função fica assim:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(x):
   if x == 0:
       return 76
   elif x == 1:
       return 121
   return  (2 * f(x - 1) - f(x - 2)) + 18
```

E agora, está tudo pronto para plotar um gráfico de x X f(x), que pode ser feito com:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(1, 20), list(map(f, range(1, 20))))
plt.show()
```

[image: plotagem da função como dada na questão, para X variando de 1 a 20]